# JMeter: Why i do not see result from Transaction Controller in Aggregate Report when While Controller is used

Tags: loops, while-loop, transactions, jmeter

I used Transaction Controller to have sum of response times of Samplers used in a While Controller but I can not see the sum of Transaction Controller results in Aggregate Report. There is only time for every request not the sum of the time that is consumed by the While Controller. If I check Generate parent sample in Transaction Controller, then I do not see any data from the loop in Aggregate Report (I should see Transaction Controller).

Is it because Transaction Controller does not work for loops?
How should I count the time in different way if I can not use Transaction Controller?

I attached the screenshot. [Screen from JMeter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe19W.jpg)

Thank You for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

Transaction Controller will show the sum only if all the samplers inside the controller are complete. If you place a while controller inside Transaction controller without any exit criteria, Transaction Controller can not show the sum as the samplers inside the transaction controller are still being executed.

Update while controller condition so that it will exit at some point.